# Spinlock sync in VC++ without mutex.h

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, visual-c++, synchronization

I'm kind of lost here.  I believe what I have here is absolutely thread safe, but I'm not sure it is.  I need a very quick spinlock mechanism for small parts of a more complex lock that optimizes thread lock and release (I need to make a larger lock that always releases threads in the order they blocked - something that doesn't happen with mutex/EnterCriticalSection). However - when it comes down to making the smallest and fastest kind of lock possible I'm not really sure what to do.

```
class SpinGate
{
private:
    volatile LONGLONG key = 0;
    volatile LONGLONG gate = 1;
public:
    void EnterGate();
    void ExitGate();
};

void SpinGate::EnterGate()
{
    LONGLONG myKey = InterlockedAdd64(&key, 1);

    while (myKey != gate) {}
}

void SpinGate::ExitGate()
{
    InterlockedAdd64(&gate, 1);
}
```

I *think* this thing I've constructed will ensure that, even if 1,000,000,000 threads try to get a key at the exact same time, they will all get a different key and hence be forced to spin until their key comes up.  But when it comes to C++, the mechanics of implementing safe reads and writes to memory without a standard library object are somewhat beyond the scope of my knowledge.

I'm curious how exactly a function like "interlockedadd64" performs two operations at once, an increment and then a read, while blocking other threads.  And whether or not this is *always* threadsafe.

Comment: The algorithm looks ok to me. Since you're just adding 1 each time you could use `InterlockedIncrement()` instead. Are you having a specific problem with your code? You may have better luck on codereview if it's just general feedback you're after.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I'm just new to these functions and I'm not sure if I understand how they work exactly.  I'm not having a problem with the code, but I don't know how much battery I would have to give it to get a collision that has a problem if there were a race condition I didn't understand in it...  It's a problem with not being sure how "Interlocked" methods work and whether it's always safe to read a volatile value.  e.g. I can't directly test this for errors well because the errors in thread synchronization are somewhat random in producing collisions.

Comment: Locks used to be fair in Windows. You'll want to read http://joeduffyblog.com/2006/12/14/anticonvoy-locks-in-windows-server-2003-sp1-and-windows-vista/ to understand the consequences of making locks fair. Note that there's still some best effort going on though.

Comment: What VS version are you using? If it is >= 2013 why haven't you use c++ atomics? Are they slower?

Comment: @Paolo: It is actually not uncommon, that you can't lock a lock, that you are already holding yourself.

Comment: @PaoloBrandoli "if you call EnterGate twice in a row (and ExitGate for some reason is not called before the second call to EnterGate) then the second call will spin forever" - that's already the behavior of a regular mutex.  There will be no recursion locking on this.  The larger lock it is a part of will permit recursion locking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think this thing I've constructed will ensure that, even if 1,000,000,000 threads try to get a key at the exact same time, they will all get a different key and hence be forced to spin until their key comes up.

Nope. The C++ `volatile` keyword doesn't provide *any* inter-thread guarantees.

> I'm curious how exactly a function like "interlockedadd64" performs two operations at once, an increment and then a read, while blocking other threads. And whether or not this is always threadsafe.

It doesn't block other threads. On modern CPUs, it just locks the cache line for the duration of the atomic operation so that no other core can access that memory location between the read and the write.

Comment: Side question, since this is tagged `visual-c++`, but it sounds like VS 2005+ (*not* the C++ standard) may in fact guarantee that `With Visual Studio 2005, the compiler uses acquire semantics for read operations on volatile variables and release semantics for write operations on volatile variables`. Or maybe I am misreading https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686355.aspx.

Comment: It then goes on to make clear that this is platform-specific. While some people do use it, I think it's pretty nuts to rely on it. (There's also lots of indications of poor writing, imprecision, and "weasel words" on that page. I wouldn't rely on it as a primary source for anything.)

Comment: (And by "platform-specific", I don't mean Windows. I mean some unspecified CPUs that "support it", whatever that means. It may mean it does nothing and only works on CPUs that just happen to work this way. Or maybe not. It's too vague to tell.)

Comment: Thank you for the followup. As I read it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd.aspx both formally specifies the `Microsoft specific` behavior for volatiles, and warns that `When it relies on the enhanced guarantee that's provided when the /volatile:ms compiler option is used, the code is non-portable.`.

Comment: And then it says, "*We strongly recommend that you use /volatile:iso along with explicit synchronization primitives and compiler intrinsics when you are dealing with memory that is shared across threads.*" So it seems odd that it says you have a guarantee and then strongly recommends you not rely on it. If the party giving you the "guarantee" says you shouldn't rely on it, I'd say you shouldn't. Sadly, the memory model on Windows is poorly documented. Nobody has any clue what they can or cannot rely on and just does what everyone else does and prays. :P

Comment: The memory model is not the Windows memory model, rather it is the Intel x86 and x64 memory models. These models are documented fully by Intel.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That doesn't help you when you're writing C++ code. You have to make all kinds of assumptions about the compiler to assume those will "flow through" to your C++ code. (Plus, who says he's using an x86 or x64 CPU? And who wants to write code that fails when a new CPU architecture comes out?)

Comment: @David When writing a synchronization primitive you can no longer hide behind abstractions. You need to code to the metal.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well, we know we're not making a high-quality synchronization primitive here for many reasons. So all we can do is make one that's guaranteed to be reliable at this level. But, sure, a real-world synchronization primitive would be designed completely differently from the start and would be totally built around deep platform/CPU knowledge.

Comment: @David Schwartz: where does it say, you could not rely on that behavior (as long as you use the appropriate compiler switch)? It just says, that they recommend to write portable code instead (I know, pretty strange comment comming from MS)

Comment: It doesn't say you can't rely on it, just that they strongly recommend that you don't. It's not clear why this is, but my guess is that they so botched the memory model that even they don't know what's actually guaranteed and what isn't and that this was an after the fact attempt to document what they actually had added when they realized that not doing anything special induced people to accidentally write CPU-specific code.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz they guarantee acquire/release semantics by default on x86 and allow to enable them on ARM. Not recommending that has nothing to do with "botched", there are just better solutions out there by now (namely std::atomic which didn't exist when they documented the extra guarantees). Just because I'd strongly recommend people to use new instead of malloc doesn't mean the latter is botched.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz "It then goes on to make clear that this is platform-specific" Since I'm working on a DirectX engine it's already going to be platform specific.  Yes I'm using /volatile:ms on x64 & x86

Comment: @ThisHandleNotInUse You are ignoring Microsoft's strong recommendation. You do so at your own peril.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz They give me no reason they "strongly recommend /volatile:iso" - they just pronounce it - while the explicit definition of /volatile:ms sounds like what I actually need.  I have no idea who wrote this documentation and why they said that.  Do you have some sort of recommendation on how I can perform thread-safe reads with /volatile:iso?  Because all I can see is /volatile:ms guarantees to make volatile reads and writes atomic...

Comment: @ThisHandleNotInUse This is a platform-specific requirement and you will have to sanely implement for every platform you need to support. Code your own `InterlockedGet` routine with appropriate code for each platform you need to support, and an `assert` or `#error` if you can't confirm the platform. That there's no well-defined Windows way to do this (that doesn't break ISO `volatile` semantics) is one of the reasons Windows threads are such a mess. (Fortunately, you can use C++11 Atomic types.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Like I said, this is going in a DX engine so there's no reason to provide this 4 - 5 line lock multiplatform support.  However, as I'm somewhat new to regular C++ I'm just now noticing that std::atomic has a "fetch_add" like "interlockedadd" winAPI.  The reason I wasn't using std::atomic was that I simply hadn't noticed they had these functions and assumed I needed a different way to fetch and add safely.  The "interlockedadd" functions were the first thing I came across trying to solve this problem.

Comment: Good choice. `std::atomic` is portable and will likely get you very close to the best performance possible on your platform. It enables you to ask for exactly what you want and not pay for anything you don't need.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz VC++ Atomic uses the same API anyway as I'm using.  InterlockedAdd64 is a redefinition of _InterlockedAdd64 defined in xatomic.h on VC++

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer. I really don't encourage developers to code their own lock mechanism. Most custom lock implementations fail any of these tests:

1. Very few home brew implementations try to guaranteed ordered fairness. (One thread running at higher priority could starve another from obtaining the lock).
2. Difficult to get right. Even more difficult to maintain. You'll be banging your head on a wall when you have bug.
3. Not actually needed when a simple Windows [CriticalSection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683472(v=vs.85).aspx) lock will suffice.

But since the OP asked, I'll take a shot at this. You might like it. Others might find fault with it.

In my implementation, I added some additional work to allow the lock to acquired recursively by the same thread.  I supposed you could take this out and be ok.

```
class SpinGate
{
private:

    DWORD _dwOwnerThread;
    LONG _ownerCount;

public:

    SpinGate()
    {
        _dwOwnerThread = 0;
        _ownerCount = 0;
    }

    void EnterGate()
    {
        LONG currentThread = (LONG)GetCurrentThreadId();
        LONG result = 0;
        bool owned = false;

        // if we own the lock, just increment it
        result = InterlockedCompareExchange(&_dwOwnerThread, currentThread, currentThread);
        if (result == currentThread)
        {
            // we own the lock, so increment and exit
            _ownerCount++;
            owned = true;
        }

        // otherwise, spin
        while (owned == false)
        {
            result = InterlockedCompareExchange(&_dwOwnerThread, currentThread, 0);
            if (result == 0)
            {
                _ownerCount = 1;
                owned = true;
            }
            else
            {
                while (_dwOwnerThread != 0)
                {
                    __asm
                    {
                        pause;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return;
    }

    void ExitGate()
    {
        LONG currentThread = (LONG)GetCurrentThreadId();
        LONG result = 0;

        // if we don't own the lock, this is a developer error!
        result = InterlockedCompareExchange(&_dwOwnerThread, currentThread, currentThread);
        if (result != currentThread)
        {
            // ERROR - Caller attempted to exit a gate he didn't own
            // ASSERT(FALSE);
            return;
        }

        _ownerCount--;

        if (_ownerCount == 0)
        {
            // give up the lock
            result = InterlockedCompareExchange(&_dwOwnerThread, 0, currentThread);
        }

        return;
    }
};
```

Comment: You spin on `InterlockedCompareExchange`. That's a disaster on x86, for many reasons. For one thing, if you share a physical core with the thread that holds the lock, you'll starve it. For another thing, when you finally do get the lock, at the most performance-critical instant, you'll take the mother of all mis-predicted branches and blow the pipelines. But, still, good try for an amateur. ;)

Comment: *But, still, good try for an amateur*.  Perhaps the nicest thing you've ever said on SO, David. :)  In any case, the Windows thread scheduler will still give *some* quantum to the thread under the lock, so it's not total starvation, but it's going to have some ill side effects. If I were to do a subsequent iteration, I'd make a lot of improvements to make this code more resemble what Enter/LeaveCriticalSection do.  But the OP wanted a Spin Lock. I'm just giving him what he wanted with all the disclaimers I thought he should know... I hope he knows what he's doing....

Comment: Even a spin lock can avoid spinning so tightly on ICE, can avoid writes in its inner loop, and can avoid the mispredicted branch. (Hints: 1) Use the `rep nop` or `pause` operation in the inner loop. 2) Don't do an ICE unless you have good reason to think it will succeed. If it's more likely to fail than succeed, just do a read.)

Comment: Updated comment. I think what you are suggesting is to do a while (_dwOwnerThread != 0){<asm pause>} before the call to InterlockedCompareExchange. Yes? I updated my answer with this suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, I would just use a CS to protect the data in the 'fair lock'.  It's hard to see how a CS could be 'critical' to something that is going to be enqueuing thread descriptors and/or events/semaphores.  Besides, unbound spinlocks, with no kernel fallback, usually fall into the 'suck badly' class.

Comment: your point 1 and 3 rather contradict each other because Microsoft's homebrew solution also doesn't guarantee fairness - for very good reasons because the performance hit is tremendous. Although I agree with your general point ;)

Comment: " I really don't approve of anyone writing their own lock mechanism" - I'm not particularly happy about it either - but mutex is already starving threads so I need to create a "queue" lock that releases threads in the order they arrived.  This is a small part of that lock - even though it would also do it - I don't want the bigger lock to spin.  This spin lock is only to alter some parameters on the queue lock (I'm going to allow it to give one thread "cut in line" priority as well)

Comment: @ThisHandleNotInUse Can you ask a new question about your outer problem? There's almost certainly a much better solution to it.